# msck repair table sync partitions and spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem when adding keyphrase `sync partitions` in spark-sql cli:

```
spark-sql> msck repair table my_table sync partitions;
Error in query: 
mismatched input 'sync' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

== SQL ==
MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table sync partitions
---------------------------^^^
```

At the same time, the same request is ok with hive cli:

```
hive> msck repair table my_table sync partitions
[2022-03-22 12:58:50] completed in 670 ms
```

Is there any workaround, to execute repair with sync partitions via spark-sql?

Comment: Could you try `ALTER TABLE my_table RECOVER PARTITIONS` instead? Also, what is your Spark version?

Comment: @mazaneicha I have spark3. `ALTER TABLE my_table RECOVER PARTITIONS` does not worked as `sync partitions` statement (I need to clean physically deleted partitions)

Comment: it should, in Spark 3.2. See SPARK-31891 https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/31097

Comment: @mazaneicha Got it. Unfortunatelly we have spark 3.0.0 on prod cluster installed

Comment: is there a solution finally? i have spark 2.4.7 i guess, if im not wrong.